# Strings "concatenation" inside a 'for' block

Tags: c, arrays, string, concatenation

I'm trying to implement some kind of "concatenation" in C to use a couple of values inside of one string.

The code looks like next:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define A "A"

int main() {

    char *textArray[] = {"a", "b", "c"};
    int intArray[] = {1, 2, 3};

    int n;
    // count intArray[] lengh
    // example taken from the https://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-number-elements-array/
    n = sizeof(intArray)/sizeof(int);

    int i;
    char *concat;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        // check if values are accessible
        printf("TEST: Macro: %s, textArray's value: %s, intArray's value: %d\n", A, textArray[i], intArray[i]);

        // making concatenation here - this will work
        concat = "Macro: " A " textArray's value: '' intArray's value: ''";

        // this will NOT work
        // expected result == 'Macro: A textArray's value: a intArray's value: 1' etc
        // concat = "Macro: " A " textArray's value: " textArray[i] " intArray's value: " intArray[i];
        printf("%s\n", concat);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code works fine when using the `A` macro's value only:

> ```
> $ ./array_test 
> TEST: Macro: A, textArray's value: a, intArray's value: 1
> Macro: A textArray's value: '' intArray's value: ''
> TEST: Macro: A, textArray's value: b, intArray's value: 2
> Macro: A textArray's value: '' intArray's value: ''
> TEST: Macro: A, textArray's value: c, intArray's value: 3
> Macro: A textArray's value: '' intArray's value: ''
> ```

But if I'm trying to use the `textArray[i]`, i.e.:

```
...
// making concatenation here - this will work
// concat = "Macro: " A " textArray's value: '' intArray's value: ''";

// this will NOT work
// expected result == 'Macro: A textArray's value: a intArray's value: 1' etc
concat = "Macro: " A " textArray's value: " textArray[i] " intArray's value: " intArray[i];
printf("%s\n", concat);
...
```

I have an error during compilation:

> ```
> $ gcc array_test.c -o array_test
> array_test.c: In function ‘main’:
> array_test.c:26:53: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘textArray’
>          concat = "Macro: " A " textArray's value: " textArray[i] " intArray's value: " intArray[i];
> ```

So the question is: what I'm doing wrong here and what is the correct way to achieve my goal?

**UPD**: The final goal is to have one string to be passed to a function like `mysql_query()`, e.g. `mysql_query(conn, concat)` where the `concat` will contain a value like `"INSERT INTO TableName VALUES('textValue', 'intValue')"`.

Comment: Why not `printf("Macro: %s %s: %d\n", A, textArray[i], intArray[i]);`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Added UPD with my goal.

Comment: Or `sprintf` if you want it stored in a variable

Comment: If you need a string, then [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) instead?

Comment: As a side note, if you're really passing this to `mysql_query`, usually **don't**. Use parameter binding instead. Concatenation can lead to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Although reading the update, you don't want to be doing what you're trying to do anyway - you want to use placeholders

Comment: @DarkFalcon Ah... Interesting - didn't know that. Newbie in C. Can I ask you please to add an answer with some short example if you a couple of minutes?

Comment: @setevoy Could you add an an exact example, given certain inputs, the resultant string of interest?  The "will contain a value like" is unclear.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Could you add your comment regarding `sprintf()` as an answer? Seems It helped)

Answer (score 1):

`textArray[i]` is run-time but string concatenation as you use, i.e. `"string1" "string2"` is only valid at compile time as the *compiler* concatenates these strings.

Using `textArray[i]` would require the compiler to insert code to evaluate `i` and the character or string in `textArray[i]` and then have code to concatenate the strings.

Answer (score 1):

"string" "string1" "string2" **is not the concatenation**. It is only one of the syntactically correct forms of the string literal.

Comment: Huh? The string literals in the source code are concatenated by the compiler into a single string literal in the object file.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie what internally compiler is doing does not matter. This term should not be used as it is very confusing for many people - which you should notice reading this topic

Answer (score 0):

`"Foo" MACRO "Bar"` where `MACRO` is `"27"` flattens to `"Foo" "27" "Bar"` at preprocessor time and then is further flattened into `"Foo27Bar"` by the compiler. You will have to use a standard string concat function to merge the other values into a new string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) comment - I found the solution using `sprintf()`.

So my code (another one, "original" one, with the same idea) now looks like:

```
...
    char *textArray[] = {"a", "b", "c"};
    int intArray[] = {1, 2, 3};

    int n;
    // count intArray[] lengh
    // example taken from the https://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-number-elements-array/
    n = sizeof(intArray)/sizeof(int);

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        // best to check needed size for malloc() using sizeof()
        // saving a query string into the `buffer` var
        sprintf(buffer, "INSERT INTO %s VALUES(NULL, '%s', '%d')" , DB_TABLE, textArray[i], intArray[i]);
        // pass connection obj + query string to the `mysql_query()`
        mysqlexec(con, buffer);
    }
...
```

And a dedicated `mysqlexec()` function:

```
void mysqlexec(MYSQL *con, char *query) {

    printf("Running query: %s\n", query);

    if (mysql_query(con, query)) {
      finish_with_error(con);
    }
}
```

And all works now:

> ```
> $ ./get_id 
> Running query: INSERT INTO ExampleTable VALUES(NULL, 'a', '1')
> Running query: INSERT INTO ExampleTable VALUES(NULL, 'b', '2')
> Running query: INSERT INTO ExampleTable VALUES(NULL, 'c', '3')
> The last inserted row id is: 3
> ```

Checking results:

> ```
> MariaDB [testdb]> select * from ExampleTable;
> +----+---------+--------+
> | Id | TextCol | IntCol |
> +----+---------+--------+
> |  1 | a       |      1 |
> |  2 | b       |      2 |
> |  3 | c       |      3 |
> +----+---------+--------+
> ```